# How to "resize" a rectangle image into a square image without losing any of the image?

Tags: html, css

How to "resize" a rectangle image into a square image without losing any of the image?

This is for a eBay listing which won't allow script tags so I would like to avoid JS and us CSS only.

http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb-examples.php
See - Examples > Resize.

Is this possible in CSS only?

Comment: Resize it, and then set **border-radius** with css, you will wont lose any quality and have round image.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution for this problem using background. If you have unknown size images can make squire thumbnail with **background-size:cover**.

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(print/the/image/path.jpg);"></div>

.thumbnail {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**background-size:cover;** -- will make any image to cover the full area.

Comment: `background-size : cover;` will crop the image...

Comment: That will never crop image but hide. http://cdpn.io/cgaKj

Comment: that is what is called "cropping" see here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)#Graphic_examples_.28photography.29

Comment: Thanks, I thought cropping means like cutting image with php. thanks again.

Comment: It is also cutting the image with php or other. Here is an example I fiddled : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/X9KJL/4/

Comment: The same but with `background-size: contain;` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from using old school CSS:

```
<img
    src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" 
    style="width:400px; "/>

<hr />

<img 
    src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" 
    style="height:100px; width:100px; "/>
```

### Explanation:

Set the width **or** the height only and the imags will be resized and keep its proportions.

Set **both** width and height and your image will be resized and proportions will be lost.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/FZ4nt/

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`object-fit`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/) does in css. Unfortunately, just a [few browsers supports](http://caniuse.com/object-fit) it.

Another solution whould be, if you use some server-side scripting (f.ex. php), get the dimensions of the image on server side, and apply padding (or transparent border) to fill the space after resizing the image.

F.ex:

Original image is 200x400, and you want to produce a 100x100 *lookalike*, you can do it with:

```
<img src=".../200x400.png"
     width="50"
     height="100"
     style="padding: 0px 25px;" />
```